# my react js get installed first and get deleted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

C:\Users\asus\Desktop\abc> npx create-react react-app
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-01T15_44_34_936Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\asus\Desktop\abc>npx create-react-app my-cart

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\asus\Desktop\abc\my-cart.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2Fparser: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-01T15_50_36_835Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-cart/ from C:\Users\asus\Desktop\abc
Done.

C:\Users\asus\Desktop\abc>npx create-react-app my-cart

please give any solution this installation

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to create a new React app but issued the wrong script/command.

```
npx create-react react-app
```

`create-react` isn't a script `npx` could find and run. `create-react` isn't the same thing as `create-react-app`.

The script/commend should probably be something more like the following:

```
npx create-react-app <your new app name here>
```

Be sure to review the [Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) guide and familiarize yourself with the CLI for the rest of the project setup and dependency installation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problems with your internet connection. You can try yarn instead of npm, it continues installs even if something happens to your connection. You can install it by typing

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and then create react app with command

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```